# What do I need to prove here?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, convex-analysis, polytopes

I found this question but I think I don't understand the question properly. The author asks to describe (in coordinates) the faces of the intersection of a cube $C$ of $r$-dimensions, $C=\{0\leq p_{s}\leq 1|s=1,...,r\}$ with a hyperplane $p_{1}+...+p_{r}=\frac{r}{2}$.

If $r=1$ then I have a line segment from 0 to 1 and the hyperplane corresponds to $p_{1}=1/2$ which is mid-point of this line segment. If $r=2$ then $C$ is a unit square with one of its vertex at the origin while the hyperplane is $p_{1}+p_{2}=1$ which is a line segment from the (0,1) to the point (1,0) and it bisects the square. And so on.

What I don't understand is how to "describe the faces of the intersection". Basically, I don't understand what I have to prove. Any kind of hint would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You have described the intersection. Now, a face is a surface of one lower dimension that is on the boundary, like the face of a cube. For an line segment, the "faces" are the endpoints.

Comment: right, but how to write the intersection in coordinate form for a general value of $r$?

Comment: The shapes get more interesting in higher dimensions. For example, if $r=3$, the intersection is a regular hexagon. The "faces" of the intersection are the six edges, which are line segments. 

In four dimensions, the "faces" of the intersection will be some kind of polygon, and in five dimensions, they'll be some kind of polyhedron.

Comment: Also: in even dimensions, the plane goes through the vertices of the cube, but in odd dimensions it does not.

Comment: How is it a hexagon if $r=3$?

Comment: Okay, I understood how it would be a hexagon in $r=3$. Thanks.